# How do I show the Alert Box first and then redirect to any page with query strings?

Tags: c#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel2, this.GetType(), "click", "alert('This Email address is already registered...');window.location.href ='test.aspx'", true);
```

By using the above code i able to show alert box and after that redirect to test.aspx page.

But problem come when i have to pass query string with address like :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel2, this.GetType(), "click", "alert('This Email address is already registered...');window.location.href ='test.aspx?WidgetID='" + Request.QueryString["WidgetID"] + "'&lan='" + readCookie() + "'&seeHome=true'", true);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has unnecessary **(')** s which breaks the string in javascript. Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel2, this.GetType(), "click", "alert('This Email address is already registered...');window.location.href ='test.aspx?WidgetID=" + Request.QueryString["WidgetID"] + "&lan=" + readCookie() + "&seeHome=true'", true);
```